# pyOpenGL Triangle isn't being drawn

Tags: python, opengl, glfw

I just started learning pyOpenGL and ran into an issue, my first project is very simple: I'm trying to open a window and  draw a simple triangle using shaders. I'm using glfw to create the window and everything compiles properly, but the Triangle isn't being drawn.

Is something wrong with my main loop or my use of a vertex buffer? My shaders  and program objects (seem to) work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import OpenGL.GL
import OpenGL
import glfw
import numpy

def createAndCompileShader(type, source):
    shader = OpenGL.GL.glCreateShader(type)
    OpenGL.GL.glShaderSource(shader, source)
    OpenGL.GL.glCompileShader(shader)


    result = OpenGL.GL.glGetShaderiv(shader, OpenGL.GL.GL_COMPILE_STATUS)

    if result != 1:
        raise Exception("Shader didn't compile properly\nShader compilation Log:\n" + str(OpenGL.GL.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader)))
    return shader


def createProgramWithShaders(shaders):

    ProgramIdentification = OpenGL.GL.glCreateProgram()

    for s in shaders:
        OpenGL.GL.glAttachShader(ProgramIdentification, s)

    OpenGL.GL.glLinkProgram(ProgramIdentification)

    linkStatus = OpenGL.GL.glGetProgramiv(ProgramIdentification, OpenGL.GL.GL_LINK_STATUS)
    infoLogLength = OpenGL.GL.glGetProgramiv(ProgramIdentification, OpenGL.GL.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)
    for s in shaders:
        OpenGL.GL.glDetachShader(ProgramIdentification, s)
    for s in shaders:
       OpenGL.GL.glDeleteShader(s)

    return ProgramIdentification


glfw.init()

glfw.window_hint(glfw.SAMPLES, 4)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, OpenGL.GL.GL_TRUE)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)

window = glfw.create_window(1000,800,"TESTING GLFW", None, None)
glfw.make_context_current(window)

glfw.set_input_mode(window,glfw.STICKY_KEYS, OpenGL.GL.GL_TRUE)

VAO = OpenGL.GL.glGenVertexArrays(1) 
OpenGL.GL.glBindVertexArray(VAO)    

vektoren = numpy.array([-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], dtype='float32')
vertexBuffer = OpenGL.GL.glGenBuffers(1)
OpenGL.GL.glBindBuffer(OpenGL.GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer)
OpenGL.GL.glBufferData(OpenGL.GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,len(vektoren), vektoren, OpenGL.GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

VertexSource = open("simpleVertexShader.glsl")
FragmentSource = open("simpleFragmentShader.glsl")

shaders = [createAndCompileShader(OpenGL.GL.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, VertexSource.read()), createAndCompileShader(OpenGL.GL.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, FragmentSource.read())]

VertexSource.close()
FragmentSource.close()
ProgramID = createProgramWithShaders(shaders)

OpenGL.GL.glClearColor(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0)

while not glfw.window_should_close(window) and glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_ESCAPE) != glfw.PRESS:
    OpenGL.GL.glClear( OpenGL.GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    OpenGL.GL.glUseProgram(ProgramID)

    OpenGL.GL.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    OpenGL.GL.glBindBuffer(OpenGL.GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer)
    OpenGL.GL.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, OpenGL.GL.GL_FLOAT, OpenGL.GL.GL_FALSE, 0, None)

    OpenGL.GL.glDrawArrays(OpenGL.GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)
    OpenGL.GL.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)

    glfw.swap_buffers(window)
    glfw.poll_events()

glfw.terminate()
```

simpleVertexShader.glsl:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexposition_modelspace;

void main(){
    gl_Position.xyz = vertexposition_modelspace;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

simpleFragmentShader.glsl:

```
#version 330 core

out vec3 color;

void main(){
    color = vec3(1,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd parameter [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) has to be the size of the buffer in bytes and not the number of elements of the array:

Calculate the size of the buffer in bytes, to solve your issue:

```
buffer_size = len(vektoren) * vektoren.itemsize
OpenGL.GL.glBufferData(OpenGL.GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer_size, vektoren, OpenGL.GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

---

Note, the array can be passed to [`glBufferData`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glBufferData.html) without setting the size explicitly:

```
OpenGL.GL.glBufferData(OpenGL.GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vektoren, OpenGL.GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```